# Read file, one line at a time and run code

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

I have a file with text in this format:

> text:text2:text3
>   text4:text5:text6
>   text7:text8:text9

Now what I want to do, is to read the first line, separate the words at the ":", and save the 3 strings into different variables. those variables are then used as parameter for a method, before having the program read the next line and doing the same thing over and over again.. So far I've got this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

BufferedReader reader = null;

try {
    File file = new File("C://Users//Patrick//Desktop//textfile.txt");
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also, I've tried this for separation (although not sure Array is the best option:

```
String[] strArr = sCurrentLine.split("\\:");
```

Comment: Is there any question here? What is your problem exactly?

Comment: The question is, how to read the first line of the text file only, separate and then set the value (text, text2, text3) as a variable in order to use the variables as parameter for a method..

Comment: I suggest to ask this in the question itself

Answer (score 1):

Use `String[] parts = line.split(":");` to get an array with `text`, `text2` etc. You can then loop through `parts` and call the method you want with each item in the list.

Your original split does not work, because `:` is not a special character in Regex. You only have to use an escape character when the split you are trying to achieve uses a special character.

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java).